# Кали Линукс зависает. Что делать ? Я ввожу пароль а дальше так и никуда не могу нажать

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот так выглядит экран после загрузки кали и введения пароля
У меня Виндовс 10 и видеокарта Intel

Comment: Эм, выглядит как загрузившаяся система. Что значит «ничего не нажимается»?